# Will two [NSDate date] following each-other always return different times?

Tags: objective-c, date, nsdate

Will dateA and dateB always be different?

```
// Two [NSDate date] following each other
NSDate *dateA = [NSDate date];    // Line X
NSDate *dateB = [NSDate date];    // Line X+1
```

That is, will the line below always return NO?

```
[dateA isEqualToDate:dateB]
```

("Always" meaning that like a very fast processor wouldn't execute the two commands so fast that dateA and dateB would be assigned the same time with "sub-second" accuracy).

I want to have a "unique" timestamp for some internal identification (not DB-related).

Comment: This strikes me as a case where this may be the wrong question, in one sense. If you told us what you're actually trying to achieve, you are likely to get better guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no promise that `dateB` will be after `dateA`. `NSDate` is based on the system clock, which can bump forward or backward based on NTP information. It would be pretty surprising to have two `NSDate` times collide, but there's no promise it won't happen.

If you need something a little better, I'd recommend `mach_absolute_time()` or `CACurrentMediaTime()`. They always increase during the run of your program. They're measure time since the last boot of the device, so they're only unique until the next reboot. If you need something that always increases, it's pretty easy to build that by keeping track of an offset. `mach_absolute_time()` tracks CPU ticks, so I don't believe two calls to it on the same thread can return the same value.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that they could be the same, although they could be depends on timing. The docs state that is returned the current time. It could change between the execution of those 2 lines, or it could stay the same if it happens fast enough.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-date

If you need uniques, then you should look at generating a GUID. Checkout this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: would you rather have a guaranteed documented unique (CFUUIDRef), or a maybe but the docs aren't clear unique (NSDate)? If someone can provide documentation that states clearly either way on NSDate, I'd love to see it.

Comment: hehe, yes my needs are in-between a "guaranteed documented unique" and a "maybe but docs aren't clear unique".. I too was hoping someone could show some clear evidence for one or the other :)

Comment: CFUUIDRef is fairly easy to use and will be guaranteed unique.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, yes. The calls to NSDate happen sequentially, not at the same time, so there will be some difference in time between the calls. But if you're looking for unique timestamps, then that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

NSDate has sub-millisecond accuracy, so it is hard to imagine a scenario where you would end up with identical timestamps. Faster future hardware would be expected to also provide timing accuracy that scales with the performance improvements.

Easy sample code—just get a series of NSDates without any intervening code. I bet they vary well above the final decimal place, which will indicate you will be just fine.