# NSDate as Dictionary Key

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

What is the real probability of using NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 as a key in a dictionary conflicting? i.e.

```
let key1 = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
let key2 = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

The above should always work as unique keys, but what if key2 was called on a separate thread at just the right moment?

Is there locking on the internals of NSDate that would prevent the one in a million error?

Comment: "*The above should always work as unique keys*." [Actually there's no guarantee about that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854932/will-two-nsdate-date-following-each-other-always-return-different-times)

Comment: Use `[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]` to generate unique keys, don't try to use things for stuff they weren't designed for

Comment: @dan That doesn't work you want to create several unique keys with the same devic. My suggestion would be to generate a random alphanumeric string with a high enough entropy to be almost impossible to be the same.

Comment: @dzk Why not? It creates a different string every time you call it

Comment: you can use NSDate as a dictionary key.

Comment: there is no conflicting. If you set a new value for the same date key the old value will be overwritten

Comment: @dan Ah sorry, I was confusing it with `identifierForVendor.UUIDString`. Yes, definitely, that will create a unique string each time.

Comment: BTW you are using a Double `typealias NSTimeInterval = Double` as your dictionary key (not a NSDate)