# Adjacent calls to [NSDate date] do not always produce different timestamps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I noticed that one of my unit tests for an iOS application was failing intermittently, and dug in to find out what was going on. The affected codepath can be simplified to:

```
NSDate *someDate = [NSDate date];

// Make a method call which accepts someDate as a param.
// Inside the method, check the param for null, and then:
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval interval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:someDate];
```

On my machine, `interval` ends up being zero every now and then, even though there is a method call and a null check between the two invocations of `[NSDate date]`. I ran the test in a for-loop with 1000 iterations, and it only took about 3 iterations to hit the case of 'interval' being zero. I put some breakpoints to confirm that the dates really were the same and it wasn't just an artifact of `timeIntervalSinceDate` losing precision.

This seems to have been observed before in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854932/will-two-nsdate-date-following-each-other-always-return-different-times), but the answers make it sound that I should be seeing this quite rarely. I wonder if it has to do with my computer, or changes to the OS, or both/neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPUs are fast.  The resolution of `NSTimeInterval` is not infinite.  `NSDate` is just an `NSTimeInterval` offset from some reference date.  If the instructions between the two calls to `[NSDate date]` take less time to execute than the resolution offered by `NSTimeInterval`, the interval between them will be zero.

Comment: I tried to find out exactly what this resolution is, but it doesn't seem to be documented. I'd sometimes see an interval of 0.00003 seconds, so it goes at least into microseconds, and NSCalendar methods for comparing dates state they could even distinguish between nanoseconds. What I don't like is the "pseudo-random" outcome that I can't predict.

Comment: `NSTimeInterval` is defined as `double`, which has a known resolution.  You'd have to delve into IEEE floating point types or find a good reference to get the resolution.  One thing I do know is that the intervals between values are not monotonic, do to the way the decimal portion of a floating point number is represented.

Comment: Anecdote: A number of years ago, I worked with a data architect (DB schema designer) who insisted that TIMESTAMP fields were perfectly valid primary keys.  She was wrong, but of course a mere developer was in no position to contradict the Holy Data Architect.  Corporate bureaucracy.  /sigh

Comment: Alright, seems like at least I have a plausible candidate explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a close look on it.The time is same(someDate and currentDate value) in debugging area. But you are getting the interval as power of e-5.Interval real value is 0.000010013580322265625

[image]

> NOTE
>
> Double has a precision of at least 15 decimal digits, whereas the precision of Float can be as little as 6 decimal digits. The appropriate floating-point type to use depends on the nature and range of values you need to work with in your code. In situations where either type would be appropriate, Double is preferred.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

So  I don't think if you have to changes the OS, computer or both/neither.

Comment: Right - the two dates' canonical representation as a string is the same in this case, and the interval between them can be either a really small value (as in your example above), or sometimes zero. In Objective-C, NSTimeInterval is already a type alias for "double", so we're not getting any float-based value truncation. The point of my post was that the case of the NSTimeInterval being zero is happening more frequently than I thought it would.

Comment: As you say "I ran the test in a for-loop with 1000 iterations" and the time interval of this iterations may be so close.for loop execution time may be a place to think. Sorry brother :) can't help beyond this.